# ReactJS two different components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I have a question regarding ReactJS components. Please bear with me as I'm just new in ReactJS. I'm stuck figuring out how to do this with ReactJS. Here's the scenario.

**SCENARIO:**

```
<div>
    <button id="download-button">Download as CSV</button> <!-- This is a ReactJS Component -->
    <h3>Filters</h3>
    <form>
        <!--
            SOME FILTER FIELDS
        -->
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </form>
</div>

<div>
    <h2>Filtered Search Result</h3>
    <div id="result" filters="<?php echo $filters ?>"></div> <!-- This is a ReactJS Component -->
</div>
```

**PROBLEM:**

Inside result component, if there's an empty result, I want to hide the download button. I understand that this is simple if download button is inside result component. But in this case, I just don't want to write all the html elements that is irrelevant inside the result component just to be able to access result button on top of those html elements.

Comment: How are you rendering reach of the components to the DOM? Are you using two different calls to ReactDOM.render?

Comment: Yes, I'm using two different calls to render. Here's how it looks like:

src/components/download-button.js
`import * as React from "react"
export class DownloadButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.download.bind(this)}>Download</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}`

src/components/search-result.js
`import * as React from "react"
export class SearchResult extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.displayResult()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

In [react](https://facebook.github.io/react/) your components can return `null` in `render()` method

So this is valid

```
// @flow
import React from "react";
Props = {
    renderNull: boolean
}
const MyNullDecoratorComponent = (props: Props) => props.renderNull && null || "some text";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you be more specific on how to use the code you posted? Actually, I am thinking of a function inside the result component saying that download button component will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can put both the Child components into one Parent component(having method checkResultLength and this.state.downloadVisible = true ).

Pass these two as props in result Component.

Check in your result component in "componentDidMount" and call the function checkResultLength passed from the parent component which will set the state.downloadVisible = false if your results.length === 0.

this.state.downloadVisible will be passed as a prop in your Filter Form component and you can hide and show it accordingly

Comment: Yes, I also thought of that. But in this scenario, I cant put them under 1 component because the download button is placed in another file because I'm using layout with my views.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should know how to communicate between two component. If this two component is parent <-> child, they can communicate by Props or function callback.

Your components are not parent <-> child relationship, so the best way is using flux data flow, You can treat your filter result as global component state.

I think you should learn Flux data flow, such as Redux, Alt.js, etc, it can resolve your problem.

I use Alt.js, Here is my demo [here](https://github.com/ThinkCats/antd-router), I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing the `result` props to the `Result` you can just easily add a guard operator to your `DownloadBtn` Component

```js
class Result extends Component {
  render () {
    const { result } = this.props // is the same with const result = this.props.result
    
    return (
      <div>
        {result.length >= 0 &&
          <DownloadBtn />
        }
        { // render results here }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```